# using an image as a link (php)

Tags: php, image

can anyone tell my why this:

```
echo "<a href='productdetail.php?product=" . $rij['productnaam'] . "'><img src='../images/producten/monster_energy_green.png' alt='' /></a>";
```

does give a clickable image link, and this:

```
echo "<a href='productdetail.php?product=" . $rij['productnaam'] . "'><img src='" . $rij['afbeelding_klein'] . "' alt'productafbeelding' /></a>";
```

doesnt? (not clickable).

thanks in advance!!
php rookie..

Comment: `alt'productafbeelding'` isn't a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: Echo the contents of `$rij['afbeelding_klein']` and see what's in it. I bet it's something that isn't a valid link

Comment: You probably forgot to  "echo" the $rij['afbeelding_klein'] variable...

Comment: First, examine the client-side result of these by viewing the source of the page.  (The server-side code has no bearing on whether something is "a clickable image link".)  Then, compare the two and find the differences.  (Hint: There aren't many.)

Comment: Is the problem that the second one ISN'T clickable or that you DON'T get an image?

Comment: What do you mean *clickable*? Do you have problem on showing the image or the link of `<a>`?

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you have a real scr it's directing to with a file extension. the second does not. If the second is supposed to be picking up a variable we would need more information

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='productdetail.php?product=" . $rij['productnaam'] . "'><img src='" . $rij['afbeelding_klein'] . "' alt='productafbeelding' /></a>";
```

just add a "=" between alt and 'productafbeelding'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
echo '<a href="productdetail.php?product=' . $rij['productnaam'] . '"><img src="' . $rij['afbeelding_klein'] . '" alt="productafbeelding" /></a>';
```

Comment: Invalid attributes will just get ignored. It doesn't "break" the image.

Comment: `'` quotes are valid in html. using them to delimite an attribute is not an error.

Comment: Anyway, it is how I write this kind of codes, and I know they work for me. If not, I have no more to say.